# Unable to run Ubuntu Software app under WSL

Tags: software-center, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I click 'show applications' on the dock, then 'Ubuntu Software'.  It starts running (I can see it in the activities bar) - but then it disappears.

I've had good success with running Gnome on Ubuntu 22.04.2, WSL is 1.2.5.0 on Windows 10.0.19044.3086.  But this piece eludes me.

TIA

Comment: in order to use snaps (which Ubuntu Software uses), you will need to enable systemd for your wsl install.

Comment: Systemd is enabled.  Confirmed via /etc/ws.conf as well as running systemctl list-unit-files --type=service

Comment: To update - I am able to run 'sudo snap install firefox' - and it installs without issue.  I guess just the GUI won't launch....